# Configuring Controls for Windows Forms and WPF inside Toolbox in Visual Studio 2012 Express edition

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I tried to configure the windows forms(4.0) and WPF products(4.0) assemblies in visual studio 2012  toolbox. But i am unable to configure the assemblies manually into Visual Studio 2012 toolbox. it shows the "There are no components in {Assembly Path} that can be placed on toolbox" error.

Also i am able create only WPF application (machine configuration-> Win 8 + VS2012 Express edition)

Can you please tell, how to configure the custom assemblies(.net framework 4.0) in VS toolbox?

Regards,
Siva S

Comment: which Express edition did you download?  Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8 will allow you to build only Windows Store apps; you need Visual Studio Express for Windows Desktop to build WPF/Windows Forms

Answer (score 1):

From `Tools` menu option select "`Customize Toolbox`" then `browse` and `select` the yourAssembly.dll assembly and `click OK.`

You will now see the control listed in the `toolboxTool`